# How can I run my flutter app full stretched for Android Q gesture navigation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: pixel phone using the new Android Q gesture navigation]

Here you can see the clock app's ui is running behind the gesture. how can i implement this in flutter? I updated flutter to 2.5 but it's not working.

This is the first question I asked on stackoverflow and i couldn't quite get the question layout. sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```dart
await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
```

in your `main.dart` before `runApp`.

As per the description of `SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge`:

> Fullscreen display with status and navigation elements rendered over the
> application.
> Available starting at SDK 16 or Android J. Earlier versions of Android
> will not be affected by this setting.
> For applications running on iOS, the status bar and home indicator will be
> visible.
> The system overlays will not disappear or reappear in this mode as they
> are permanently displayed on top of the application.